# Rewrite rule for non ascii charactors, hyphen, underscore and brackets?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to allow for non ascii characters to be in my urls.

In the past I was running the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/([\w()-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I need make a change to allow for non ascii characters such as é

So I replaced [\w()-] with [-0-9a-zA-Z\W]

```
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/?$ rewrite.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
```

When I access **/abc/abc/abcabc/abc/abéééééé/**

It works correctly however now some of my urls that were previously working that are basic ascii paths such as **/abc/abc/abcabc/** are now showing an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Any idea why? Is there a better rewrite rule to allow for A-Z 0-9 ( ) - _ and non ascii characters?

Comment: _"Any idea why?"_ - because `\W` matches any non-word character - so you are, among other things, also allowing for a `.` now - and so `^([-0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/?$` also matches on `rewrite.php`, which means your already rewritten request gtes rewritten _again_ in the next "round."

Answer (score 0):

OK so I have been playing with chatgpt the past 30 minutes trying to solve this

This seems to work so far

`RewriteRule ^([^\s/]+)/([^\s/]+)/([^\s/]+)/([^\s/]+)/([^\s/]+)/`